# A practical example of evenly distributing n lists into a single list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, vba, excel

I had previously asked about how to evenly distribute the items in n lists into a single list and was referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344860/good-algorithm-for-combining-items-from-n-lists-into-one-with-balanced-distribut).

I made a practical example of my solution for this in VBA for Excel, since my application for this was resorting my Spotify lists which can be easily pasted into Excel for manipulation. Assumptions are that you have a headerless worksheet (wsSource) of songs with columns A, B, C representing Artist, Song, SpotifyURI respectively, a "Totals" worksheet (wsTotals) containing the sum of songs for each Artist from wsSource sorted in descending order, and a "Destination" worksheet where the new list will be created.

[Here's](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?page=view&resid=13B1F82ADE0040FB!2604&authkey=!AClcvAegnBj5X24) a link to the sample file.

Could I get some suggestions to improve this? I was going to get rid of the totals worksheet and have this portion done in code, but I have to go and I wanted to go ahead and put this out there.

```
Sub WeaveSort()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTotals As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim iLast As Integer
Dim iDest As Integer
Dim iSource As Integer
Dim iOldRow As Integer
Dim iNewRow As Integer
Dim dDiff As Double
Dim dDiffSum As Double

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTotals = wb.Worksheets("Totals")
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Source")
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Dest")
    iLast = wsTotals.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1

    For i = 2 To iLast
        iSource = wsTotals.Range("B" & i).Value
        iDest = wsDest.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row

        If i = 2 Then
            wsDest.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2 = wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2
            wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Delete (xlShiftUp)
            GoTo NextI
        End If

        dDiff = iDest / iSource
        dDiffSum = 0
        iNewRow = 0

        For iOldRow = 1 To iSource
            dDiff = iDest / iSource
            dDiffSum = dDiffSum + dDiff
            iNewRow = Round(dDiffSum, 0)
            wsSource.Rows(iOldRow).Copy
            wsDest.Rows(iNewRow).Insert xlShiftDown
            iDest = iDest + 1
        Next iOldRow

        wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Delete (xlShiftUp)
NextI:
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 11):

One word.... ***VELOCIRAPTORS***.

[image: xkcd GoTo]

You seem like a nice guy, I don't want the raptors to get you, so let's take [Heslacher's advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59691/41243) and move this code outside of the loop.

```
    If i = 2 Then
        wsDest.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2 = wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2
        wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Delete (xlShiftUp)
        GoTo NextI
    End If
```

Since we'll handling the special case of the first row outside the loop, we need to change which row the loop starts on. While we're at it, let's get rid of that magic number and replace it with a variable. Note that I also replaced `i` with the more meaningful name `row`.

```
iSource = wsTotals.Range("B2").Value
wsDest.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2 = wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2
wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Delete (xlShiftUp)

Dim startRow As Long
startRow = 3
For row = startRow To iLast
    iSource = wsTotals.Range("B" & i).Value
    iDest = wsDest.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row
```

Now that the dreaded `GoTo` has been banished, let's see what else we can clean up.

- There's no sense in assigning `ThisWorkbook` to a variable. There's no need to keep an extra reference to it in memory. Just do this. (Note that although I *hate* hungarian notation, I find using `wb` for workbook and `ws` for worksheet acceptable. The intention is clear to any VBA developer.)

  ```
  Set wsTotals = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Totals")
  Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
  Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dest")
  ```
- Your method of finding the last row has [unpredictable results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11169445/3198973). Use this instead.

  ```
  lastRow = wsTotals.Range("A" & wsTotals.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  ```
- Same deal with finding the destination row.

  ```
  iDest = wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  ```

Applying most of [Vogel612's naming suggestions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59687/41243), this is the code up to this point.

```
Sub WeaveSort()

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTotals As Worksheet
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim destinationRow As Integer
    Dim sourceRow As Integer
    Dim oldRow As Integer
    Dim newRow As Integer
    Dim difference As Double
    Dim differenceSum As Double

    Set wsTotals = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Totals")
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dest")

    lastRow = wsTotals.Range("A" & wsTotals.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row - 1

    sourceRow = wsTotals.Range("B2").Value
    wsDest.Range("A1:C" & sourceRow).Value2 = wsSource.Range("A1:C" & sourceRow).Value2
    wsSource.Range("A1:C" & sourceRow).Delete (xlShiftUp)

    Dim startRow As Long
    startRow = 3
    For row = startRow To lastRow
        sourceRow = wsTotals.Range("B" & row).Value
        destinationRow = wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        difference = destinationRow / sourceRow
        differenceSum = 0
        newRow = 0

        For oldRow = 1 To sourceRow
            difference = destinationRow / sourceRow
            differenceSum = differenceSum + difference
            newRow = Round(differenceSum, 0)
            wsSource.Rows(oldRow).Copy
            wsDest.Rows(newRow).Insert xlShiftDown
            destinationRow = destinationRow + 1
        Next oldRow

        wsSource.Range("A1:C" & sourceRow).Delete (xlShiftUp)
    Next row

End Sub
```

We introduced a little duplication when we got rid of the raptors. Let's introduce a sub to delete the data from the source. To make things easy, we'll declare the different worksheets at the module level.

```
Option Explicit

Private wsDest As Worksheet
Private wsSource As Worksheet
Private wsTotals As Worksheet

Private Sub DeleteFromSource(ByVal row As Long)
    wsSource.Range("A1:C" & row).Delete (xlShiftUp)
End Sub
```

Changing `WeaveSort` to:

```
Sub WeaveSort()

    Dim row As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim destinationRow As Integer
    Dim sourceRow As Integer
    Dim oldRow As Integer
    Dim newRow As Integer
    Dim difference As Double
    Dim differenceSum As Double

    Set wsTotals = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Totals")
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dest")

    lastRow = wsTotals.Range("A" & wsTotals.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row - 1
    sourceRow = wsTotals.Range("B2").Value

    wsDest.Range("A1:C" & row).Value2 = wsSource.Range("A1:C" & row).Value2
    DeleteFromSource sourceRow

    Dim startRow As Long
    startRow = 3
    For row = startRow To lastRow
        sourceRow = wsTotals.Range("B" & row).Value
        destinationRow = wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        difference = destinationRow / sourceRow
        differenceSum = 0
        newRow = 0

        For oldRow = 1 To sourceRow
            difference = destinationRow / sourceRow
            differenceSum = differenceSum + difference
            newRow = Round(differenceSum, 0)
            wsSource.Rows(oldRow).Copy
            wsDest.Rows(newRow).Insert xlShiftDown
            destinationRow = destinationRow + 1
        Next oldRow

        DeleteFromSource sourceRow
    Next row

End Sub
```

Ultimately leaving this clever solution unchanged, but much more understandable.

Answer (score 5):

Passing on the wisdom here, it's seldom that I review vba, I hope someone more competent comes along and touches on the aspects I didn't touch. (read: everything but names)

### Variables:

> ```
> Dim wb As Workbook
> Dim wsDest As Worksheet
> Dim wsSource As Worksheet
> Dim wsTotals As Worksheet
> Dim i As Integer
> Dim iLast As Integer
> Dim iDest As Integer
> Dim iSource As Integer
> Dim iOldRow As Integer
> Dim iNewRow As Integer
> Dim dDiff As Double
> Dim dDiffSum As Double
>
>     Set wb = ThisWorkbook
>     Set wsTotals = wb.Worksheets("Totals")
>     Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Source")
>     Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Dest")
> ```

There's a lot to say here.
First off: Constants. The workbooks' names will never change, so I'd declare them as constants:

```
Const totalsWSName As String = "Totals"
Const sourceWSName As String = "Source"
Const destinationWSName As String = "Dest"
```

And use as:

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsTotals = wb.Worksheets(totalsWSName)
Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets(sourceWSName)
Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets(destinationWSName)
```

next up, names. You use some quirky naming here.

I am not fond of misusing hungarian notation, opposing to how it was originally intended. There's a nice article by [Joel Spolsky on apps hungarian vs systems hungarian.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) I recommend you read it, because he's higlighting some very important aspects on when to use hungarian notation and when **not**.

In your code you use systems hungarian. This is the bad sort. I recommend you distance yourself from using hungarian notation to prefix types. Your variable names should show what exactly you mean.

```
wb --> workbook
wsDest --> destinationSheet
wsSource --> sourceSheet
wsTotals --> totalsSheet
i --> i
iLast --> totalsRows
iDest --> destinationRow
iSource --> sourceRow
iOldRow --> oldRow
iNewRow --> newRow
dDiff --> difference
dDiffSum --> differenceSum
```

The types are not exactly relevant and make understanding the variable name harder. I tried to rename the variables so they express what they are doing, without being prefixed with anything.

In general it can be said:
Avoid hungarian notation wherever possible, because you are likely to get it wrong. And if you can't help using it, using it fully through the bench usually is not the correct way.

So much from my side ;)

Comment: The names of the worksheets could be constants, but the workbook themselves have to be assigned to a variable at runtime.

Comment: @ckuhn203 dammit. Would have been so nice ;) check the edit.

Comment: It would be nice wouldn't it? Your edit works, but a constant for a string that appears once might be overkill. =) Regardless, you had my up vote for mentioning the Hungarian notation.

Comment: very informative article! most of my experience has been with vba, where programmers apparently still live in the dark ages of systems hugarian notation. thanks for showing me the light!

Answer (score 5):

To what [Vogel612](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/37660/vogel612) already has written I would like to add that you should refactor this

> ```
> If i = 2 Then
>     wsDest.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2 = wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2
>     wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Delete (xlShiftUp)
>     GoTo NextI
> End If
> ```

to be outside of your outer loop. You can also remove `iNewRow = 0` and `dDiff = iDest / iSource`, because you are assigning new values inside the inner loop to these variables.

**Edit**
After reading [ckuhn203](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/41243/ckuhn203) answer, I see what I have forgotten. The starting index of the outer for loop needs to be changed to 3.

```
iSource = wsTotals.Range("B" & 2).Value
wsDest.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2 = wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2
wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Delete (xlShiftUp)

For i = 3 To iLast
    iSource = wsTotals.Range("B" & i).Value
    iDest = wsDest.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row

    dDiffSum = 0

    For iOldRow = 1 To iSource
        dDiff = iDest / iSource
        dDiffSum = dDiffSum + dDiff
        iNewRow = Round(dDiffSum, 0)
        wsSource.Rows(iOldRow).Copy
        wsDest.Rows(iNewRow).Insert xlShiftDown
        iDest = iDest + 1
    Next iOldRow

    wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Delete (xlShiftUp)

Next i
```

Comment: iSource is the count of items in the current list being moved and is the limit of the inner loop, so I think it needs to be recalculated for each list if all else remains the same.

Comment: @ForrestA, As `wsTotals` won't change inside the loops `iSource` won't change and therefor won't need to be recalculated. `iSource = wsTotals.Range("B" & i).Value`

Comment: I think I may be having a brain fart, but let's say in wsTotals Range("B2") = 12 and Range("B3") = 9. If I don't redefine iSource after i gets incremented from 2 to 3, my iSource will still be 12 even though the list now being moved from wsSource to wsDest only has 9 items. I'm still a little sleepy though, so let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: A perfect example of why I should change my variable names, as @vogel612 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to follow up on this. I changed up the algorithm a little. Instead of inserting items into a new list, each item's final place is calculated up front. Sort of like if instead of resizing an array each time I add a new item, I'm sizing it up front and just setting the value of each element. If the place is already occupied, the closest open place is found. This avoids everything getting shifted around as new items are inserted into the list, so every item is as close as possible to it's ideal place in the new list. Let me know if this needs to be a new thread.

```
Sub TrueShuffle()

    ' object declarations
    Dim xl As Object ' Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Object ' Excel.Workbook
    Dim destinationWs As Object ' Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sourceWs As Object ' Excel.Worksheet
    Dim totalsWs As Object ' Excel.Worksheet

    ' variable declarations
    Dim artistName As String
    Dim quotient As Double
    Dim quotientSum As Double
    Dim timeElapsed As Double
    Dim pivotRows As Integer
    Dim songCount As Integer
    Dim artist As Integer
    Dim song As Integer
    Dim artistSongs As Integer
    Dim oldRow As Integer
    Dim newRow As Integer
    Dim adjustment As Integer
    Dim first As Integer
    Dim sign As Integer

    ' start timer and turn off screen updating
    timeElapsed = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' set xl objects
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set totalsWs = wb.Worksheets("Totals")
    Set sourceWs = wb.Worksheets("Source")
    Set destinationWs = wb.Worksheets("Dest")

    ' opening operations
    songCount = sourceWs.Range("A1").End(xlDown).row - 1    ' total songs in destination sheet
    totalsWs.PivotTables("SongCount").ChangePivotCache _
        wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase _
                            , SourceData:="Source!A1:C" & songCount + 1)   ' set pivot data source range
    totalsWs.PivotTables("SongCount").RefreshTable    ' refresh pivot table
    pivotRows = totalsWs.Range("B1").End(xlDown).row    ' total rows in pivot table
    destinationWs.Cells.Delete    ' clear destination sheet

    ' iterate through each artist in pivot table
    For artist = 2 To pivotRows - 1
        artistName = totalsWs.Range("A" & artist).Value2
        artistSongs = totalsWs.Range("B" & artist).Value2    ' song count for current artist

        Select Case artist
        Case 2    ' first artist takes first place in destination list
            oldRow = sourceWs.Range("A2:A" & songCount + 1).Find(artistName, sourceWs.Range("A" & songCount + 1)).row
            sourceWs.Range("A" & oldRow & ":C" & oldRow).Copy destinationWs.Range("A1:C1")
            quotient = (songCount - 1) / (artistSongs - 1)
            quotientSum = 1
            first = 2    ' first song is placed before loop, so start from second song
        Case Else
            oldRow = songCount + 1    ' set to ensure the search for an artists songs starts from the beginning of the source list
            quotient = songCount / artistSongs
            quotientSum = (-quotient) / 2    ' offset placement within the list by half the quotient
            first = 1
        End Select

        For song = first To artistSongs
            ' insert each song into destination sheet by incrementing by the
            ' artistSongs:songCount quotient and rounding to the nearest integer
            quotientSum = quotientSum + quotient
            oldRow = sourceWs.Range("A2:A" & songCount + 1).Find(artistName, sourceWs.Range("A" & oldRow)).row
            newRow = Round(quotientSum, 0)

            On Error Resume Next

            ' find the closest empty space
            adjustment = 1
            sign = 1

            Do While destinationWs.Range("A" & newRow).Value2 <> 0
                newRow = newRow + adjustment
                adjustment = (adjustment + sign) * (-1)
                sign = sign * (-1)
            Loop

            On Error GoTo 0

            sourceWs.Range("A" & oldRow & ":C" & oldRow).Copy destinationWs.Range("A" & newRow & ":C" & newRow)
        Next song
    Next artist

    ' clear objects from memory
    Set totalsWs = Nothing
    Set sourceWs = Nothing
    Set destinationWs = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing

    ' turn on screen updating and calculate time elapsed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    timeElapsed = Timer - timeElapsed

    MsgBox "TrueShuffled " & songCount & " songs in " & Round(timeElapsed, 2) & " seconds!", , "You Just Got TrueShuffled!"

End Sub
```